# basic jQuery Gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with a small jquery problem. I have no knowledge in writing jquery back am proficient in HTML CSS and implementing jquery plugins.

I am building a gallery page to this web site. Currently i have got a row of thumbnails in a jquery carosel that works perfectly.

HERES WHAT I NEED:

When the user clicks a thumbnail i want its large image to cross fade over the top of the large image that is currently on the stage (the first thumbnail).

Im sure this is simple enough for anyone who has a basic knowledge of writing jquery.

Here is my current source code.

http://www.silverbackstudios.co.uk/laurenmitchell/wedding-gallery.html

Thank you for your help!

Jarrett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add an ID to your big image

```
<img id="gallery-big" src="images/gallery/wedding/large/1.jpg" width="940" height="445" />
```

After that I'd change the names of the images so that the large image and the thumbnail both have the same name but are put in different folders, like this:

```
images/gallery/wedding/large/1.jpg
images/gallery/wedding/thumbs/1.jpg
```

When that's done you can add the following JQuery code

```
var clickable = true;

$(document).on("click", ".thumb a", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    if (clickable == true)
    {
        clickable = false;

        // Get URL of the large image
        var nameIMG = $("img", this).attr("src");
        nameIMG = nameIMG.replace("thumbs/", "large/");

        // Fade in the new image
        $("#gallery").append('<div class="big-overlay"><img src="' + nameIMG + '" width="940" height="445" /></div>');
        $(".big-overlay").fadeIn("slow", function()
        {
            // Change the original <img> to the new image
            $("#gallery-big").attr("src", nameIMG).load(function()
            {
                // Remove the overlay
                $(".big-overlay").remove();
                clickable = true;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

...and the following CSS rule

```
.big-overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}
```

What this code does is that it adds an overlay containing the large version of the clicked thumb image and fades it in. When that's done it changes the search path of the original image (#gallery-big) and then removes the overlay.

It might not the best solution, but it should do the job :)

Comment: thanks for your help! i think i have done everything you said correct but its not working. The image is just opening in its own window. Here is the updated source: http://www.silverbackstudios.co.uk/laurenmitchell/wedding-gallery1.html

Comment: might have missed something, will have a look at it

Comment: @jarrettowen - changed the JQuery code a little and it should work now. Btw, you must add the #big-overlay CSS to your stylesheet, which you haven't done yet. http://www.fameuppsala.com/test/test.html for a demo (only 2nd thumb works since you haven't added large images for the others)

Comment: thanks. it all work fine apart from at the end of the crossfade the image disapears then reapears for a split second creating a jolty effect. Is there any way of stoping this? I really appreciate your help! :-)

Comment: @jarrettowen - It has to do with the new image having to load. You can always add a delay to the remove() function to give it a little extra time to load. Also, you should give the overlay DIV a class instead of ID, since there is a second there where you could end up with 2 divs... I'll change my code above, so have another look at it please

Comment: @jarrettowen - I'm quite new to JQuery myself, so I don't know any ways to make sure the image has loaded before executing another function, but like I said in previous comment, adding a delay like that will buy you some extra time. I don't recommend you to increase it, but if it doesn't make much difference for you, just make the delay a bit longer.

Comment: @jarrettowen - Btw, since your problem's been solved you might want to click the "tick" next to my answer to let others know that your question's been answered :) If you run into more problems, let me know

Comment: how do i add a delay? i will try that. p.s Tick sorted! thanks

Comment: @jarrettowen - Check my code above. Added in the delay :) it's just an added delay() to the remove() line, just like this $(".big-overlay").delay(200).remove();

Comment: Unfortunatly the image still jumps :-( at the moment the gallery is un-usuable. Thanks for your efforts tho Tom

Comment: @jarrettowen - It's because you haven't changed the width and height of the .big-overlay DIV in the JQuery append() function. The width and height must be the same as the #gallery-big image

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Light box plugin.

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used lightboxes before but they are not what i want for this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it yourself then add the `data-src="location_of_full_size_image.jpg"` to the thumbs and in `onClick` method to thumbs

```
$('#gallery-big').attr('src', self.data('src'))
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. unfortunately i will need a little help trying to implement your suggestion. Can you give me an example in context. Or talk me through it on skype. Thanks